# Webpack - dependency not found

Tags: javascript, webpack, laravel-mix

I just started using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) which is using webpack. I'm having some issues resolving dependencies.

I tried to install `l20n` with `npm install l20n`, added it to my project by adding `require('l20n');` and then I ran `npm run dev` only to be told the following:

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                

This dependency was not found:

* fs in ./~/l20n/dist/bundle/node/l20n.js
```

Alright, so I figured I had to install fs too, issuing `npm install fs` and then I ran `npm run dev` again, but I get the exact same message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if this has any effect, but did you try installing **and** saving it to your package.json, i.e. `npm install l20n -S` ?

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis Yes I did, with both packages, but it's still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I checked out the source and I think I know what the issue is. The lib you are using is supposed to run in a node environment.

So, in your webpack configuration add this:

```
  target: 'node'
```

For more info on targets see [this](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/)